# What are the criteria for being "No One"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In ["Oathbreaker"](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Oathbreaker), the third episode of the sixth season of *Game of Thrones*

> Arya drinks the water from the fountain in the House of Black and White to gain back her eye-sight.

I haven't read the books, but from the series alone my understanding is that

> only people who are truly "No One" can drink the water without being harmed. The Faceless Man also says something along those lines just before Arya drinks the water.

**So what are the criteria for being truly "No One"?**

> In particular Arya still strives to kill the names on her list.

Is this maybe the purpose of the brotherhood? To become "No One" you have to give up everything except for a list of names that you intend to offer to the god of many faces? Like I said, haven't read the books, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to not hide the entire question behind huge empty boxes?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i felt they were all massive spoilers, especially for people who havent watched season 5. the main question is visible. do you have any particular suggestions for improving on this issue?

Comment: @Numrok agreed on the 1st two. Not sure if the third spoiler block is really protecting anything that 'spoiler-y'

Comment: @kuhl thanks for the input, i tried an edit. is this better?

Comment: @Numrok yeah, that looks a lot better to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there are no official rules given we can infer to become No One a person must fully realize that their service is to Many-Faced God and not any personal reasons.

The only reason Jaqen offered Ayra three names at Harrenhal is **[because she saved three men who were supposed to be claimed by the gods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h9u-0DCoqs)**

> Jaqen: Only death may pay for life... You stole three deaths from the
> Red God, we have to give them back.

In this scene Ayra shows she is ready. (start at about 2:45 for quote)

> Waif: That can't be everyone you want to kill; are you sure you are not forgetting someone?
>
> Arya: Which name would you like a girl to speak.

This shows she has moved beyond her own wants. She is willing to accept killing anyone.

Comment: @Skoba: +1, you get that accept if you manage to link a video that doesnt get blocked ;-).